# How to play wav file in IE 10/11

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to play `.wav` file in IE 10/11. I have tried playing `.wav` files in IE 10/11 but it does not work properly.

I am looking specificaly for `.wav` file support in IE 10 /11 and other IE versions.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying?

```
<embed src="themesong.wav" hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="1">
```

for automatic

and

```
<a href="clicknoise.wav">Play Sound</a>
```

for click should work.

Comment: did you checked .wav file support in ie 10 or 11

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible :(
According to those sources (2015-08-24):

[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=wav) -> doesn't work (you have to use Edge)

[w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) -> doesn't work

Solution: You could convert it to MP3 which is supported by all browsers (more or less)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion